# Namespace/Assembly errors in "Views" section in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces, .net-core, .net-assembly, visual-studio-2017

I have a .Net Core application that I used to develop on "back in the days of Visual Studio 2015". I have now moved on to Visual Studio 2017 and back to this project and I have a need to rename the project. I started following numerous guides online on how to rename a Visual Studio project, however none of them seems to support .Net Core and Visual Studio 2017. I believe it is important to mention that the only part of my project that complains about the namespace is the "Views" section, and it only seems to refer to files that have been created/edited recently.

After doing the following, I have still not found a solution:

- Rename Solution in solution explorer.
- Rename project in solution explorer.
- Changing Assembly name in "Project" -> " Properties".
- Changing Default namespace in "Project" -> " Properties".
- Going to Program.cs and changing namespace using "Right-click" -> "Rename" -> "Rename all occurances".
- Adding "@using " in _ViewImports.cshtml (complains about missing namespace here as well).

I am getting desperate as I feel like I have tried everything and nothing seems to works.

I have recently renamed my project from MobileFront to MSPFrontend and even if I change the "@using" statements inside my _ViewImports.cshtml back to MobileFront it still complains.

I am hoping that I am not the first one to encounter this tedious problem.

## EDIT

I noticed the errors occured only when the files were open. I don't know if this is important to know of whether it has some importance for finding the solution.

Comment: Yeah, I have kind of the same issues. My views always complain about missing `System` namespaces, but ONLY when I open them. However, if I run my application it all works fine and no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: I continued to try a bunch of things, such as downgrade from NetCoreApp 1.1.2 to 1.1.1 and so forth. Finally I tried to create a new project and once I went back to my original project (the one I have trouble with) it seems that the errors have magically disappeared.

Comment: welcome to the world of .NET Core and extremely stable tooling haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downloading `Microsoft.AspNetCore` version 1.1.1 through NuGet. After doing that I created a completely new project and reopened my original project. That solved the problem. All of a sudden my project could find all namespaces and assemblies.